# How to increment the speed of a sprite using x coordinates on update()?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

very beginner and probably dumb question. I'm following along a tutorial about PhaserJs, and i need to increment gradually the speed of the sprite i'm moving on keyboard press.

I've tried to set an auto increment, but it seems it's not working properly.

here's what i have so far to move the sprite on the x with the same speed.

```
function create() {
  gameState.codey = this.add.sprite(150, 200, 'codey')
  // Set cursor keys here!
  gameState.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

}

function update() {
  // Update based on keypress here!
  let speed= 5;
  if(gameState.cursors.right.isDown) {
    gameState.codey.x+=5
  }
```

with that code, the sprite is moving at the same speed hitting the right arrow. But what if i want to make it accelerate gradually?
i've tried to do "`` gameState.codey.x = x++" but is not actually working.

Thanks for any help and sorry for the super dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

Phaser has a built-in Physics system that will greatly simplify what you're trying to do. Update your game config to include the `physics` attributes like this:

```
var config = { 
  ...
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade'
  },
  ...
};
```

This gives you access to the Arcade** Physics engine [API Doc](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.ArcadePhysics.html). It handles things like velocity & acceleration for you so you're not manually incrementing speed on button presses.

Once you've incorporated the physics engine, you can update your sprite to be physics-controlled like this:

```
gameState.codey = this.physics.add.sprite(150, 200, 'codey');
```

If you only want your player to move when a button is pressed, you'll want to add this after you declare your player:

```
gameState.codey.setVelocity(0, 0);
```

And then, for handling the incremental speed of your player, you'd update your `update()` to look like this:

```
function update() {
  ...
  if(gameState.cursors.right.isDown) {
    gameState.codey.setVelocityX(5).setAccelerationX(5);
  } else { // no buttons pressed
    gameState.codey.setVelocity(0, 0).setAcceleration(0, 0);
  }
}
```

You can see more of the methods and properties the Arcade Physics engine makes available to your sprites [here](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite.html).

**Just a note: Phaser offers multiple physics engines -- Arcade is just one choice. You can see the other options in action [here](http://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=physics/&q=).